# HighCharts works only in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, google-chrome, highcharts

I want to create a graph using Highcharts plugin and the data should be parsed as an XML file.
The XML file data2.xml is,

```
<data>  
<row><t>1347559200</t><v>2.1600000000e+01</v></row> 
<row><t>1347562800</t><v>2.1504694630e+01</v></row> 
<row><t>1347566400</t><v>2.1278633024e+01</v></row> 
</data>
```

The HTML coding is,

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>line chart</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    options = {
      chart: {
          renderTo: 'container',
          type: 'spline'
      },
      title: {
          text: 'Temperatures'
      },
      subtitle: {
          text: 'An example of time data in Highcharts JS'
      },
      xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
          dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
              month: '%e. %b',
              year: '%b'
          }
      },
      yAxis: {
          title: {
              text: 'T (°C)'
          },
          min: 0
      },
      tooltip: {
          formatter: function() {
                  return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                  Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b', this.x) +': '+ this.y +' m';
          }
      },

      series: [{
          name: 'Temperature',
          data: []
      }]
    }

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data2.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      var series = {  data: []
                  };

      $(xml).find("row").each(function()
      {
          var t = parseInt($(this).find("t").text())*1000
          var v = parseFloat($(this).find("v").text())
          series.data.push([t,v]);
      });
      options.series.push(series);
    }
  });

  chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I execute this code It opens fine in Internet Explorer and displays the result as

[image: Result in Internet Explorer]

When I open this file in Chrome it gives me the result as,

[image: Result in Google chrome]

with the error message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/data2.xml. Origin null is not allowed by Access-    Control-Allow-Origin.
```

so that I used Tomcat server to run this. Though it displays the same chart image without the mentioned error message.

How to overcome this?? How can I display the chart in Google Chrome by fetching data from xml file by solving this issue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working out..
I just run this code by using Apache/Tomcat..

I think the error I have made is that 
1. I have to save this file in .jsp format.
2. add var to chart and options variable.
3. Use this `chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);` inside the success function.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a security restriction in Chrome to stop malicious web pages from accessing your local files. See more about this at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

You can disable it temporarily by running chrome from the command/dos prompt with the switch `--disable-web-security`

e.g. `chrome.exe --disable-web-security`

alternatively try running the page from a local web server. [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/windows.html) and [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html) are available for free if you don't have access to [IIS](http://www.iis.net/)

Comment: Though I used the given command in DOS and opened the Chrome it is showing me the same error

Comment: Eventhough I used Apache to run this code.. Its not drawing the graph. By now I'm not getting the error the emtpy document with the title and axis are mentioned. How to get rid of this issue??

Comment: Sorry the flag didn't work out for you. That's the same one I use on linux and osx.  The chart is empty because you need to move the line `chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);` to inside the success function. Currently the chart is being drawn before the ajax call has finished loading the data.